# PHP COUNT_RECURSIVE and SplFixedArray

Tags: php, spl

I'm seeing some odd behavior with count( $arr, COUNT_RECURSIVE ) when used with [SplFixedArray](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php).  Take this block of code, for instance...

```
$structure = new SplFixedArray( 10 );

for( $r = 0; $r < 10; $r++ )
{
    $structure[ $r ] = new SplFixedArray( 10 );
    for( $c = 0; $c < 10; $c++ )
    {
        $structure[ $r ][ $c ] = true;
    }
}

echo count( $structure, COUNT_RECURSIVE );
```

Result...

```
> 10
```

You would expect a result of 110.  Is this normal behavior due to the fact that I'm nesting SplFixedArray objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SplFixedArray` implements `Countable`, but `Countable` does not allow for a arguments, hence you cannot count recursive. [The argument is ignored.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/cYRmFU) You can see this from the method signature of [`SplFixedArray::count`](http://php.net/manual/en/splfixedarray.count.php) and [`Countable::count`](http://php.net/manual/en/countable.count.php).

There is a Feature Request open for this at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58102

---

You can sublass `SplFixedArray` and make it implement `RecursiveIterator` and then overload the `count` method to use `iterate_count` but then it will always count all the elements, e.g. it's always `COUNT_RECURSIVE` then. Can also add a dedicated method though.

```
class MySplFixedArray extends SplFixedArray implements RecursiveIterator
{
    public function count()
    {
        return iterator_count(
            new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                $this,
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
            )
        );
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->current();
    }

    public function hasChildren()
    {
        return $this->current() instanceof MySplFixedArray;
    }
}
```

[demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/76Kcj4)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I had checked into that this morning but couldn't find anything.  I knew I was overlooking something.  Thanks!